# Calling nested callback functions in javascript using chrome apis

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.bookmarks.create({parentId: nodeId, title: title},function(bmNode) {
  chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(window) {
     chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(window.id, function(tabs) {
        for(var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++) {
           chrome.bookmarks.create({parentId: bmNode.id, title:tabs[i].title,
                                   url:tabs[i].url});
        }
     });
   });
});
```

Basically I am trying to get all the open tabs in the current window and then create a bookmark folder and add all the tabs to it. It used to work fine till now, suddenly it stopped working. The root folder bookmark is created but the links are not added to the folder.

I know its a lot of nested calls which are asynchronous but how do i make sure all of them execute.

Comment: Does the developer tools inspector show any errors in your extension's page?

Comment: sadly no, i didnt get any errors. it used to work until sometime ago. but then started acting on its own.

Comment: Are the missing closing parentheses intentional? (you never close the opening parenthesis from the `chrome.bookmarks.create`, `chrome.windows.getCurrent`, and `chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow` calls)

Comment: oh sorry about that, was trying to format the code and i forgot to put the closing braces. will edit the code.

Comment: Try console.log  create events maybe you will see the problem ?

Comment: i tried that too, but the nested callback functions themselves are not called so console.log doesnt print anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a minor thing that i had overlooked. I found out that I was calling "location.reload()" function which was upsetting the whole async callback structure. I removed that and it started working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

it would seem to me that bmNode is null when you refer to it.

I would create bmNode synchronously and then go for enumerating the tabs.

```
var bmNode = chrome.bookmarks.create({parentId: nodeId, title: title} )

  chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(window) {
     chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(window.id, function(tabs) {
        for(var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++) {
           chrome.bookmarks.create({parentId: bmNode.id, title:tabs[i].title,
                                   url:tabs[i].url});
        }
     });
   });
```